# JS to generate HTML table, but one first row cell won't get value, comes up as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I have a function that's below (I broke the lines after innerHTML so it's easier to see) and the forloop generates a table, with id's for each tags. I'm wanting to calculate the total of each item(quantity * price).

The function works fine after the first row, but first row's total returns an undefined value, which i'm assuming is because the variables are declared later on.

How could i possible solve this issue, and work out the total?[image]

The relevant JS:

```
function load() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= localStorage.length - 1; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    document.getElementById(key).setAttribute('checked', 'checked');    
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<tr>
<td><input type='text' class='name' id='name-" + i + "' value='" + key + "'disabled /></td>
<td id='quantity-" + i + "'>
<input type='text' class='quantity' id='input-" + i + "' value='1' disabled/>
<button class='update' id='increment-" + i + "' onclick='incrementQuantity(this);'>+</button><button class='update' id='decrement-" + i + "' onclick='decrementQuantity(this);'>-</button></td>
<td id='price-" + i + "'></td><td>" + totalPrice + "</td>
<td><button class='delete' id='delete-" + i + "'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
    var name = $('#name-' + i).val();
    var id = $('#' + name);
    var price = id.data('price');
    var quantity = document.getElementById('input-' + i);
    var quantityValue = quantity.value;
    var total = price * quantityValue;
    document.getElementById('price-' + i).innerHTML = '£' + price;
    var getQuantity = $('#input-' + i).val();
    var totalPrice = price * getQuantity;
  }
}
```

Local storage's data:

key: photo2, value: checked

key: photo6, value: checked

key: photo7, value: checked

Comment: can you post data of local storage?

Comment: @eramit2010 I added it

Comment: "The function works fine after the first row". No it doesn't - it's showing the results for the previous row, quite clearly. You're writing your total to the next row instead of the current once, mainly because you aren't actually calculating the total until after you have added the HTML where the total is supposed to appear!

Comment: @ADyson How would i be able to calculate the total beforehand? If i don't have the id's generated, i won't be able to access their attributes.

Comment: you still have the values which you're putting into those IDs. e.g. you're defaulting Quantity to 1, and clearly you know the price since you already have a variable for it. So you can calculate that easily before you create the HTML. The logic should be fairly simple: create all of the values you need, then create the HTML which is populated using those values.

Comment: @ADyson I was able to do it now after your explanation, I just had to get rid of a line of code and insert it after the html generation. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You are updating total after appending dom. you need to calculate everything before updating it to DOM.

```
function load() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= localStorage.length - 1; i++) {
    var key = localStorage.key(i);
    var id = $('#' + key);
    var price = id.data('price'); // assuming this will be there in dom
    var quantityValue = 1; // adding this 1 in table
    var total = price * quantityValue;
    document.getElementById('price-' + i).innerHTML = '£' + price;
    var getQuantity = 1;
    var totalPrice = price * getQuantity;
    document.getElementById(key).setAttribute('checked', 'checked');    
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML += "<tr>
<td><input type='text' class='name' id='name-" + i + "' value='" + key + "'disabled /></td>
<td id='quantity-" + i + "'>
<input type='text' class='quantity' id='input-" + i + "' value='1' disabled/>
<button class='update' id='increment-" + i + "' onclick='incrementQuantity(this);'>+</button><button class='update' id='decrement-" + i + "' onclick='decrementQuantity(this);'>-</button></td>
<td id='price-" + i + "'>£" + price  + "</td><td>" + totalPrice + "</td>
<td><button class='delete' id='delete-" + i + "'>Delete</button></td></tr>";
  }
}
```

Comment: If i do this, nothing will appear in the table

Comment: updated answer. assuming there is one div with price as data attribute.